# How to pass query time out parameter to DB2 stored Proc

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have a interface where users can select a stored proc and pass parameters to the stored proc.

Based on what the user selects, the query can run for a long time.

If the query takes more than 5 minutes I want to stop the query and send an email to the user asking him to contact the developer.

Basically how do we pass a time out parameter to query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do it in the same SQL stored procedure, because this is a sequential execution, and there is not any possibility to fork a connexion or perform a parallel execution.

You can eventually create a external stored procedure in Java or C, that will create a thread for monitoring purposes and then trigger the finalisation of the job if it is getting too much time.

Also, you can create an infinitive loop in a SP that will be activated each minute to check the processes, and kill the ones that have taken more than a certain quantity of time, but this is NOT recommended.

You can use the built-in module [UTL_MAIL](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0055176.html) to send an email and terminate a process via [admin_cmd](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023574.html) but you have to create a monitoring process in parallel, and that is not possible from the same connexion.

You can check a Serge Rielau's article in his blog that could give you many ideas: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/sleep?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Query timeout is a client configuration parameter, set via `db2cli.ini`, `db2dsdriver.cfg`, or the JDBC connection property, depending on the client version and type. To enforce query run time limit on the server side, where the stored procedure runs, you will need to use Workload Manager.

In either case I don't think you'll be able to trigger an email notification to the client.